# Maximum length of repeating digits in a decimal

Tags: decimal-expansion

Total math novice here. I'm wondering if (as I think should be the case) there is no maximum length of a repeating decimal period, for example:

```
- 0.33333... (period 1)
- 0.252525... (period 2)
- 0.142857142857... (period 6) 
- etc.
```

The reason I am curious about this is that I have learned that the decimal expansions of irrational numbers don't terminate or repeat. But if there is no upper limit to the period that a repeating decimal can have, then where is the difference between the two? I am guessing that although the repeting pattern can grow without bound it is always finite (I think?) whereas with an irrational number the pattern never restarts again after a finite period. But it still makes my head hurt :-) so I am wondering if there are any explanations for it that I might be able to understand as a non-practitioner.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6):

To answer the first part, yes these period can get arbitrarily large. Take a look at the number:
$$ \frac{1}{10^n-1}$$

For $n=1$, this gives $\frac{1}{9}=0.1111...$

For $n=2$, this gives $\frac {1}{99}=0.010101...$

For $n=3$, this gives $\frac {1}{999}=0.001001001...$

The decimal expansion of each number has period $n$ (the decimal expasion is just the repeating pattern of $n-1$ zeros followed by a $1$), and we can make $n$ as big as we would like.

For the second part of your question, the difference is that irrational numbers *don't* have a period. It's not that they have an infinitely large period after the decimal place; they just don't have a period whatsoever. They never get to a point where they start repeating. If the number ever continues to infinitely repeat itself, then that number is a rational number.

The difference is that *every* single individual rational number has a *finite* period. There are rational number with whatever finite period size we want, but there is never a rational number with an infinite period size.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and detailed explanation!

Comment: For a concrete example, consider converting between pounds and kilograms of mass. By international agreement, the pound is defined as exactly 0.45359237kg. If you take the reciprocal of that number to get the number of pounds in a kilogram, the result's decimal expansion has a period of 2,248 digits!

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you're right. Rational decimal expansions repeat *eventually*. You may have to go for millions or billions of digits, but they'll repeat - you can always find some number $n$ so after some point in the string of digits every $n$th digit will be the same. Irrational ones don't repeat at all.

Comment: Wow, mind-bending but I can see the difference. Thanks for the answer!